# Java thread causes deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I' m trying to implement some basic start, stop, pause and resume functionality that allows me the following state transitions:

- stopped to running
- running to stopped
- running to paused
- paused to running
- paused to stopped (causes deadlock)

Most of this works as expected, but the last state transition is not possible, because it makes the thread freeze. Could someone please explain me why that is happening and how to prevent it? Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean running = false;
    private volatile boolean paused = false;
    private Thread thread;

    public ThreadTest() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                if (paused) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        while (paused)
                        wait(); 
                    }
                }   
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if(running && !thread.isAlive())
            return; 
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if(!running && thread.isAlive())
            return;  
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join(); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         System.exit(0);    
    }

    public synchronized void resume() { 
        if(paused) {
        paused = false; 
        notify();
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void pause() { 
        if(!paused) {
            paused = true; 
            }
            else {
                return;
            } 
        }

}
```

Comment: Try to call `notify()` in `stop()` method in `paused` case. You locked your thread by `wait()` calling.

Comment: @SeniorJD: Pls see my answer and my comment to xagyg on why notify() wont work.

Comment: +1 because your question was useful for me (made me think) !

Answer (score 3):

`wait();` in run method will wait forever becuase these is not `notify();`
When call stop, the thread is running becuase wait for ever, so `thread.join()` will lock.
You need call notify in stop or change wait for ever to `wait(1000);`

Comment: wait(1000) will not work. This is because, when the wait call timesout, the runnable thread (lets call this as T2) running the run() will automatically try and re-acquire the lock on the ThreadTest object (which it released just before entering the wait). But that lock is already held by the main thread (inside the stop() method, where it is waiting to join() on the T2 thread) ! So, even if the wait(1000) timesout, it will never resume execution inside the run() method.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the `stop` method, call `thread.notify();` just **after** `running = false;`. (This will notify the waiting thread).
2. Then you **must** set `paused = false;` just before your notify call.
3. Remove the `if (paused)` block from your `run` method.
4. Change your `while (paused)` loop to `while (paused && running)`. Alternatively, you could use `while (paused) { wait(); if (!running) break;}` depending on what control flow you want.
5. For good measure, add the `volatile` keyword to the `paused` and `running` variable declarations (to create memory fences across threads).

Comment: That didn't work, because the application is still hanging when I try to end/quit when it is paused.

Comment: pls see my answer below on why notify() will not work ! Another reason why notify() may not work is when T1 executes stop() (and hence the notify()) before T2 enters the wait ! This leads to a missed wake-up !

Comment: @user1812379 you need to remove the `if (paused)` block from your run method.

Comment: @vendhan That's correct. I have added use of the flag `running` which solves that problem.

Comment: @user1812379 I have updated my answer. Should work now. If you have further problems let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Let us see what exactly is happening here: 
Let us name the threads involved here as T2 (the Thread that you explicitly instantiated and started in your code) and T1 (which invokes the start, stop methods on the T2 thread **Object**). T1 is probably your main thread, depending on your other unshown code.

You are getting a Deadlock because of the following sequence of events:
(**Note1**: This is just one possible sequence, there may be other possible sequences in this code which could also cause a deadlock)

Say we do a start(), pause() and then a stop() on the ThreadTest object as follows (say in main()):

```
ThreadTest t = new ThreadTest();
t.start();
t.pause();
t.stop();
```

1. After the pause() executes in T1, T2 acquired a lock on the ThreadTest object by entering the "synchronized(this)" block inside the "if(paused)" condition. (**Note2**: The "this" here refers NOT to the T2 thread object, but it refers to the ThreadTest object as run() is a method on the ThreadTest class.)
2. T2 enters into a wait() and releases the ThreadTest object lock (implicitly) just when it enters that wait() call.
3. When T1 enters stop(), it acquires a lock on the ThreadTest object as stop() is a synchronized method. Inside stop(), T1 calls t2.join(), and waits for T2 to complete.
   But T2 is already in a wait() and has no one to wake it up !

Hence the Deadlock !

**Note3**: Even if we wake T2 up by specifying a timeout in the wait() call or by calling notify() (as suggested by others), it still cannot come out of the wait because it cannot re-acquire (implicitly) the lock (on ThreadTest object), as that is already held by T1 waiting in the join() !

**One possible solution:**
While there could be many possible solutions, can you try this one ?

In the stop() method, instead of

```
thread.join();
```

can you use:

```
if (!paused) {
  thread.join();
} else {
  thread.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. One question left: Why can't a separate lock object be used here?

Comment: a seperate lock object where ? can you pls add more detail to what you want >